# Unexpected identifier error with horizontal line plugin for chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I am trying to plot a bar chart and display some horizontal lines at y=1 and y=3 on the bar chart. Someone on a forum had recommended using plugins to do this, however when I tried (as shown: https://jsfiddle.net/prbo0f2y/7/) the console kept prompting `unexpected identifier`. Does anyone know where the error is? I am using chart.js (version 2.5) and Bootstrap 3. The error seems to point to this part of the code:

```
options: {
    "horizontalLine": [{
        "y": 3,
        "style": "rgba(255, 0, 0, .4)",
        "text": "max"
    }, {
        "y": 1,
        "text": "min"
    }]
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click here:

[image: Click here]

Then it shows you exactly where the error is:

[image: the error]

… with a fading out yellow highlight to show you the line starting `scales:`.

**You need to put a comma between each key:value pair in an object literal.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a syntax error (e.g. missing comma) in your `options` config between `horizontalLine` and `scales`.

With that said, may I recommend that you use the [`chartjs-plugin-annotation`](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation) plugin to do this instead.  This is a plugin created/supported by the same guys who created chart.js and in addition to drawing lines, it provides more functionality should you need it in the future.

Here is a horizontal line configuration example.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
      borderWidth: 2,
      fill: false,
      data: [2, 10]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Drsw Line on Chart'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: true
    },
    annotation: {
      annotations: [{
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'horizontal',
        scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
        value: 5,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        borderWidth: 4,
        label: {
          enabled: false,
          content: 'Test label'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

You can also check out this [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/qrXJLW) that demonstrates the above.

Comment: Hi again Jordan! That looks really neat. I will try that out too. Thanks again!

Comment: In order to improve my answer, would the downvoter be able to leave a comment?